# Audit triggers in SQL Server without loops or sys tables

Tags: sql-server, triggers, pivot, audit

I've reviewed the other questions surrounding the Audit table logic, but haven't been able to hit upon what I've been tasked with creating.

My audit table basically stores the primary key, the column name that was inserted/updated/deleted, and the value of the column. The requested function uses only data from the inserted or deleted table, and nothing from the `sys` schema or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views. Likewise I cannot have any loops of any type in the trigger.

I've considered using the `PIVOT` function but my understanding is that requires an aggregate function of some sort - which is not (?) relevant here. The logic proposed to me is something like:

```
INSERT INTO someAuditTable
SELECT something FROM inserted
```

but with each column *IN* inserted having it's own row, i.e. rotated.  Finally, it has to be a one-size-fits-all trigger for each table, with varying number of columns and data types.

So is this possible? Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this happen? I'm scratching my head.

Comment: Why not e.g. `INSERT dbo.audit SELECT key, col1 FROM inserted UNION ALL SELECT key, col2 FROM inserted...`?

Comment: Because the column names, and the keys, are different among tables.  I could get the primary key and column names from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views but the requirements disallow that.

Comment: So? You have to write a different trigger for each table.

Comment: That's my initial thought, my supervisor was hoping for a way to create a single query that would fit all tables regardless of the number of columns, or their data types.

Comment: You should tell your supervisor that this is not the way to optimize code or productivity.

Comment: You might ask your supervisor how they would "reassemble" a row at a given point in time when you split all the columns apart into an EAV auditing situation. EAV has its place but imho auditing is not one of them. It is only a matter of time until some manager wants to know what the table looked like on a given day three years ago and it takes you a whole day (or longer) to put it back together.

Comment: I agree with both points here ... but overall it's not the best optimization solution.  The logic is that if there's a DDL change, the trigger for each business object table should be updated to reflect that change.  We have other options in place for knowing what a given business object was like on a certain day.  Aaron's solution appears to be the most appropriate.  Bottom line is I don't see a quick, efficient way to do this without writing triggers for each table and manually updating them on the "rare" instances when the DDL does change.